# Python sorting error

Tags: python, sorting

When I try to sort my list in python I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/natep/OneDrive/Documents/I.T/Level 2/programing/Shop_list.py", line 81, in <module>
    products.sort(key = lambda  x:x[3], reverse=True)
Name        Measurement     Price       Unit Price
  File "C:/Users/natep/OneDrive/Documents/I.T/Level 2/programing/Shop_list.py", line 81, in <lambda>

products.sort(key = lambda  x:x[3], reverse=True)
Chips   Drink   
IndexError: list index out of range
50  2.0     
5.0     3.0     
2.5     1.0     
Chips   Drink   
50  2.0     
5.0     3.0     
2.5     1.0     
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Below is the code I am using.  I would like to know how I can sort my list that contains lists.  Would also like to know why my data is being printed twice and how to format the printing output better so that it corresponds to the correct column.  (without importing downloads)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
unit_price = price / measurement
unit.append(unit_price)

products.append(name_sum)
products.append(mes_sum)
products.append(money_sum)
products.append(unit)
row_entry.append(products)

average = "The average product price is ${}".format(mean(money_sum))
highest = "The most expensive item is ${}".format(max(money_sum))
low = "The cheapest item is ${}".format(min(money_sum))

print()
print("Name\t\tMeasurement\t\tPrice\t\tUnit Price" )
for item in products:
  print("")
  for data in item:
    print(data, "\t", end='')

products.sort(key = lambda  x:x[3], reverse=True)
```

I have added all my code below:

```
# Shopping list
from statistics import mean
from operator import itemgetter

def limit_check(type, question, low, high):

    valid = False
    error = "please enter values between {} and or equal to {}".format(low, 
high)
    while not valid:
        try:
            response = type(input(question))
            if low < response <= high:
                valid = True
                return response
            else:
                print(error)
        except ValueError:
            print(error)

products = []
mes_sum = []
money_sum = []
name_sum = []
unit = []
row_entry = []

money = float(input("please enter your budget: $"))

get_data = True
while get_data == True:

name = input("please enter product name: ")
if name.lower() == "xxx":
    break
else:
    name_sum.append(name)
    price = limit_check(float,"How much does the item cost", 0, money)
    money_sum.append(price)
    measurement = limit_check(int,"Please enter unit of measurement Push 1 
for kg, push 2 for g, push 3 for L, push 4 for mL",0,4)


    if measurement == int("1"):
        kg = limit_check(float, "Enter Kg: ", 0, 10)
        mes_sum.append(kg)

    elif measurement == int("2"):
        grams = limit_check(int, "Enter Grams: ", 0, 999)
        mes_sum.append(grams)

    elif measurement == int("3"):
        litres = limit_check(float, "Enter Litres: ", 0, 30)
        mes_sum.append(litres)

    elif measurement == int("4"):
        mL = limit_check(int, "Enter mL: ", 0, 999)
        mes_sum.append(mL)

    unit_price = price / measurement
    unit.append(unit_price)


    for i in range(len(name_sum)):
        products.append([name_sum[i], mes_sum[i], money_sum[i], unit[i]])

average = "The average product price is ${}".format(mean(money_sum))
highest = "The most expensive item is ${}".format(max(money_sum))
low = "The cheapest item is ${}".format(min(money_sum))



print()
print("Name\t\tMeasurement\t\tPrice\t\tUnit Price" )
for item in products:
  print("")
  for data in item:
      print(data, "\t", end='')

products.sort(key = lambda  x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

Currently prints like this:

Name        Measurement     Price       Unit Price

looooool    1.0     10.0    10.0
looooool    1.0     10.0    10.0
lol     1.0     1.0     1.0
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: What does your data structure look like? It isn't clear.

Comment: can you please post the products list?

Comment: Why do you treat: money_sum, mes_sum, name_sum etc - as if they are products ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to expect that the lists in the `products` list each have 4 elements (for Name, Measurement, Price, and Unit Price), but in reality your data only have two elements in each list (for Chips and Drink).

Then when you try to sort `products`, which contains lists of length 2, you access the 4th value in the `lambda` function. This triggers the error: there are only two values, not 4.

It looks like you have transposed the data that you wanted to end up in `products`. Instead of:

```
products.append(name_sum)
products.append(mes_sum)
products.append(money_sum)
products.append(unit)
```

do:

```
for i in range(len(name_sum)):
    products.append([name_sum[i], mes_sum[i], money_sum[i], unit[i]])
```

Or more compactly:

```
products.extend(list(map(list, zip(*[name_sum, mes_sum, money_sum, unit]))))
```

Comment: Hi Trincot, thanks for your help.  It worked but the first value prints twice for some reason.  Also the length of the name affects the spacing in my printed output.  Would appreciate your feedback.  I have pasted all of my code above.

Comment: The code you pasted into your question has bad indentation. Could you please fix it? Make sure the code I provided is not part of your `while` loop, but comes after it.

Comment: Thanks, That stop it from printing the first item twice. Is there any way I can make the name of the product have no effect  on the placement of the numbers for example this is my print now: